# C# If Ping Response False Time is very Long

Tags: c#, ping

I want to control all the pc's in our system. I'm sending a ping request to their IP. My code is as follows:

```
public static bool PingHost(string nameOrAddress)
{
    bool pingable = false;
    Ping pinger = new Ping();
    try
    {
        PingReply reply = pinger.Send(nameOrAddress);
        pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch (PingException)
    {
        // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
    }
    return pingable;
}
```

I tried different code for ping but problem is same. If ping success. Response coming fast. But if ping unsuccessful response coming long time. 
I want to ping all pc ips.

Comment: Maybe start a timer when the ping request is sent and after a set interval have the method return false, the request took too long to respond.

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  If you are that could give a clue as to why it's taking so long.

Comment: You can set the timeout period for ping https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf697k33(v=vs.110).aspx